# Axios POST request in cycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to save a list of dishes in my restaurant's menu. I do it like this:

```
fromFormMenu.forEach(fromFormMeal => {
    MealAPI.create(fromFormMeal, restaurant.id).then(resp => console.log(resp))
})
```

In this case, the dishes are saved to the database in the wrong order in which the user entered them into the form. Here is what my API method looks like:

```
static async create(meal, restaurantId) {
    const response = await axios.post(REST_URL + "/" + restaurantId, meal);
    return response
}
```

It is necessary for me that the order of records was saved such as they were entered by the user. I assume that the problem is related to the asynchrony of requests, because of which the records are stored in random order. I even tried removing the 'async' in the method declaration, but that didn't work.

Comment: is it necessary to call thecreate APIs separately or you can club them and send in a one API call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of getting the wrong order is you're calling all the api at the same time. If some of them is finished faster than the previous items, it will be saved before them.

So in this situation you might wanna call the next api after the first one is finished.

Something like:

```
const mainFunction = async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < fromFormMenu.length; i++) {
    const resp = await MealAPI.create(fromFormMeal, restaurant.id)
    console.log(resp)
  }
}
```